# Creating a readonly version of POCO objects in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have a simple DTO class like this:

```
@interface MYNugget
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *color;
@end

@implementation MYNugget
// automatic @synthesize
@end
```

And I then later want to store this object in ***another class*** in a way such that it is not modifiable (that is, make the `color` property readonly via a `- (void)freeze` or something.

What is the best way to accomplish this short of writing my own setters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is to have to classes, one mutable and an immutable one.

```
@interface MYNugget
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *color;
@end
```

and

```
@interface MYMutableNugget : MYNugget
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *color;
@end
```

Your other class would just expose a `MYNugget` property, ideally again as `copy`. That's how we do it with `NSString` all the time.

Comment: So only the `MYMutableNugget` class would have setters defined right? Does this works with automatic @synthesize as well?

Comment: Yes, that should work just fine - and it really matching the "standard" classes we work with. If you want to make your class *great*, implement NSCopying protocol as well (fairly trivial).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is set the color via the constructor only:

```
@interface MYNugget
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *color;

- (id) initWithColor:(NSString *)color;

@end

@implementation MYNugget

@synthesize color = _color;

- (id) initWithColor:(NSString *)color {
   self = [super init];

   if (self) {
     _color = [color copy];
   }

   return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is a good approach but it does not scale well for class with more than a few properties.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I think the solution by Eiko is the one that will suit your needs if you habe meny properties/